# add different search link on chrome extension manifest.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, manifest.json

i want to change the search link by language

example default search engine (Lang EN):

```
    "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
        "name": "Example",
        "keyword": "example",
        "search_url": "https://example.com/search/?q={searchTerms}",
        "favicon_url": "https://example.com/favicon.ico",
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "is_default": true
    }
```

},

and in Italian i want to change the search link 
from `https://example.com/search/?q={searchTerms}` to `https://example.com/it/search/?q={searchTerms}` how i can do this? is this possible?

Comment: No such feature so you can suggest it on https://crbug.com. The closest thing you can do is to use an additional URL parameter like `&lng={language}`

Comment: Thanks for your help